# Непонятная работа условия else

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание:

*Заданы две клетки шахматной доски. Если они покрашены в один цвет, то выведите слово YES, а если в разные цвета — то NO. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки.*

В коде ниже, при определённых условиях, программа работает неправильно:

```
cell_1 = str(input()) + str(input())
cell_2 = str(input()) + str(input())

if int(cell_1 + cell_2) % 2 == 0:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

К примеру, если задать на вход числа "2", "3", "8", "8", то она выдаёт **YES** вместо **NO**. Не особо понятно, как это фиксить. Я даже не знаю, где можно посмотреть, что происходит на *строке №4*.

Comment: @itethebite, что вам мешает добавить отладочную печать перед строкой 4? `print(int(cell_1 + cell_2) % 2 == 0)`, `print(int(cell_1 + cell_2) % 2)`, `print(int(cell_1 + cell_2))` и т.д. пока не поймете, в чем причина.

Comment: @dzhioev, видимо то, что для человека у которого возникли сложности с типом данных на 3-й задаче, второго параграфа pythontutor.ru это сложновато

Comment: Ошибка в том, что если к 23 прибавить 88, то должно получиться 111, но у вас получается 2388.

Comment: Вторая (вернее первая и по сути там же самая) ошибка в том, что при вашем способе определения через сумму нужно складывать не 23 и 88, а 2, 3, 8 и 8. Ошибки в первых двух строчках. И как написано в самом первом комментарии - если что-то идет не так, то нужно выводить на печать содержимое переменных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваш `else` ведёт не так как вы ожидали, то скорей всего в ваше условие или условия закралась ошибка.

Я не смог настроить свой мозг на решение задачки через сумму. Если делать сумму - то избавляемся от понимания основы всей этой конструкции маленькой матрицы:

```
белое черное
черное белое
```

Любой случай можно свести к этому варианту через деление на размер этой матрицы (то бишь 2). Получим следующий код:

```
k, m, n, p = input(), input(), input(), input()
tt = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
if tt[k % 2][m % 2] == tt[n % 2][p % 2]:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: По поводу суммы: если координаты заданы целыми числами, в 1-м ряду, допустим, первая 1, 3, 5, 7 клетки черные, остальные белые. Во втором ряду 2, 4, 6, 8 клетки черные, остальные белые. Дальше получается закономерность, что если сумма координат нечетная - то клетка черная, если сумма четная - то белая. Т.к. нужно просто сравнить, что клетки одного цвета, то не важно какого цвета угловая клетка, главное чтобы четность двух сумм была одинакова (обе суммы четные или обе нечетные).

Comment: как работает я понял, но если мы начнём масштабировать решение... увеличим количество столбцов рядов на разные значения, добавим еще 3 цвета, будет ли метод сумм работать? Вот подход с матрицей будет рабочим.

Comment: если есть частный случай, и простое решение для него, то стоит использовать простое решение, а не выдумывать многоцветные шахматные доски. Это учебная задачка в конце концов, никаких других досок не предполагается.

Comment: а как же системный подход? для программистов он же так важен...

Comment: Программисты в первую очередь решают практические проблемы, а не гипотетические. Если в ТЗ сказано, что доска двухцветная 8 на 8 клеток, то достаточно реализовать вариант. Если пытаться учитывать все варианты, то можно еще вспомнить что в некоторых играх доска вообще не прямоугольная, и прочие очень специфические случаи, которые лежат далеко за рамками исходного ТЗ.

Comment: Ваша логика понятна - спасибо за комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи на pythontutor у меня, в свое время, получилось такое решение:

```
x1, y1 ,x2, y2 = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if (x1 + y1) % 2 == (x2 + y2) % 2:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

UPD: В комментарии я тоже ошибся, поэтому его удалил и перепишу здесь:
`if (int(cell_1) + int(cell_2)) % 2 == 0:`

---

И еще, для того, чтобы выполнить код пошагово (debugging своего рода) на pythontutor в редакторе есть специальная галочка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: * debugging ...

Comment: Таки да, спасибо, поправил.